# unwanted freestyle lines with poor-geometry sketchup import

Tags: geometry, freestyle

I'm a street designer who usually works in Sketchup/AI, looking to move my rendering to Blender. Having issues with unwanted freestyle lines on an imported Sketchup model of a street design. The geometry is triangulated very irregularly due to street striping and segmented arcs from Sketchup and this seems to be causing freestyle to do strange things. I have used this freestyle line setup in the past on simpler models and it has worked well. My contour lines (pink) are appearing in the middle of the street plane and at other unexpected locations. See the attached images of the render with freestyle, screen cap with wireframes, and freestyle settings to see the issue.

I've tried edgemarking these lines and excluding them but that doesn't work. Apart from totally remodelling the road, does anyone have advice about what's going on and how to fix?

Thank you!
Pete

[image: model space with wireframes]

[image: render with freestyle lines]

[image: freestyle settings]